# RegEx to match a specific text between a string and a comma (in a string with different values separated by commas)

Tags: regex

Considering a string composed by several comma separated tags, I have to match/extract the text after a specific prefix. For example I have this string:

```
CAT:SPORT_BAMBINO,CAT:SPORT_SNEAKERS,COLOR:BIANCO,EV1,FEED-MPN-GW6511,GENDER:RAGAZZO,GENDER_GROUP:RAGAZZO,NC_SPORT,Omnibus: Not on sale,PRZ:BEST SELLER:B63DBA,R:4,SCARPE-SPORT,SEASON:SS23,SUBTYPE:S3540,TG:ADI_S_KIDS
```

I highlighted the text/tag I need to match in bold; in this case I have to match/extract: **GW6511**

The prefix I have always and is `FEED-MPN-` and I have to match/extract the text after this prefix and till the next comma.

I try different solutions to write the RegEx but I was not able to find a right expression that could fit any string/tags there can be (I have thousands of different items).

Comment: Do you have a preferred language where you want to use the regex.

Comment: Is the text always uppercase letters and numbers? Or can there be lowercase letters? Or can be there by other symbols (including dashes and underscores)?

Comment: I can have numbers, letters (upper and lower cases), no symbols except "-" and "_".

Comment: The language is English.

Comment: I meant a preferred programming language.

Comment: Maybe even [`FEED-MPN([^,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZRlk2z/1) would suffice (depending on input).

Comment: Yeah, the programming language must be ENG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `FEED-MPN-<X>` can also be the first or last item in the "list", I propose the following RegEx:

[`(?:^|,)FEED-MPN-(.+?)(?=,|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4xN1PB/2)

Explanation:

- `FEED_MPN` must be preceded by the start of string (or line, depending on your flags) or a comma. We do not want to match the comma or `FEED_MPN`, so we use non-capturing groups `(?:...)`.
- Now comes the suffix `(.+?)` which we want to lazily match until...
- ... we encounter the end of string/line or a comma, which we don't want to match.

Comment: Top! It works very fine. Thanks for this solutions, You solved my issue! 

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
(?<=,FEED-MPN-)[^,]+
```

This pattern says to match:

- `(?<=,FEED-MPN-)` assert that comma followed by `FEED-MPN` precedes
- `[^,]+` then match the following term